# Using CSS in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I currently have a website with a typical homepage that uses it's own css file and then the rest of the site using one other css file. Could anyone advise on the best way to tailor my Rails app to meet these requirements?

I currently have a welcome controller with a welcome css file but not sure how to link all my other controllers to a main css file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your css files in

> app/assets/stylesheets

then in the views use:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "the_css_file_name_with_no_extension" %>
```

Actually, css files and assets in general don't get associated with controllers, but with views.
I suggest you have a read to:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

If you want to use your controllers, you can define a global variable, and use it to conditionally include different stylesheets in your application.html.erb.
Something like:

> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% if @css = "main" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "main" %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<% end%>
```

where `@css` is set to `"main"` in your main controller.

Comment: thanks but I assume that I should really be using the application.css manifest file at some point???

Comment: I've read that many times but can't find a solution/guidance on the best way to tackle this issue.

Comment: in the application.css file you put references to all the stylesheets you want to use in ALL your views. If you want to apply the DRY principle to your case, you may create a partial containing stylesheet link tags and add it at the top of your views.

Comment: i have home.css and main.css - they don't work together meaning that both may make references to p tag for example and set the styling slightly differently. Therefore, I can't just use one application.css file

Comment: That's what I was saying: application.css contains references for ALL your views, therefore you can't use it. I'll edit the answer with a different solution.

Comment: ...ok, but then won't I miss out on the benefits of the application.css manifest file (if there are any?) just because of what has to be a very common scenario?

Comment: your suggestion is much appreciated but a global variable seems a bit "heavy-handed" don't you think? Surely a situation like this is common place right and I can't believe there isn't a standard practice to handle a scenario like this!

Comment: so do I actually need application.css? and should I just make my two css files work together?

Comment: personally, I would use application.css just for importing common stylesheets, if any. If you want two separate stylesheets, why not? The first part of my solution should do.